# What is the best way to model one-to-many relationship, when you cannot use embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say you have a video, and each video can have comments, obviously, that is a one-to-many relationship. The simplest way to model that in Mongo is to use embedded documents. However, if you have thousands of comments, that would become just terrible.

So there are two options:

1. Store comment ids in a list in video document
2. Store video id in comment document

The first one has a problem of what happens if multiple users try to update the comment id list at the same time, chances are some data and ids will be lost, so not the best option.

The second one doesn't have that problem, but is a performance taking a hit by having to lookup video id in every comment document?

So what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: "if you have thousands of comments, that would become just terrible." - why? Unless almost **every** video gets thousands of comments and as long as the documents are smaller than 16MiByte, then you are fine. Note, the most commented video on YouTube has around 14 millions comments. Having thousands of comments is rather unlikely I would assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first option, you also need to lookup to get comment details since you store only comment ids.

I advice to use second option. One lookup is not that bad. Even you have performance problem, you can add index on video_id field in comments collection to perform it better.

So the lookup can be something like this:

```
db.videos.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "video_id",
      "as": "comments"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nKeTapdBkxe)

Another alternative is getting the comments with another query without lookup.
You get the video in one query and get the video comments in another query.